# How to use br tag in web scraping to get a better output?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this site [Link](https://www.uae-business-directory.com/directory/umm-al-quwain/umm-al-quwain/building-contractors/abdulla-salem-contracting-est.html).
And I am trying to scrape this particular part, Please find the HTML below:

```html
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <h1>
    ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING EST
  </h1>
  <strong>
   <a href="directory/umm-al-quwain/umm-al-quwain/building-contractors.html" title="Building 
   Contractors in Umm Al Quwain">
      Building Contractors
   </a>
</strong>
  <br> P.O. Box: 200
  <br> Location: Umm Al Quwain
  <br> Phone: 06-7655445
</div>
```

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def comp_links():
    url=requests.get("https://www.uae-business-directory.com/directory/umm-al-quwain/umm-al-quwain/building-contractors.html").text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
    links=soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^directory/umm-al-quwain/umm-al-quwain/building-contractors/")})
    return links
def comp_details(z):
    filename='comp.csv'
    f=open(filename,'w')
    music=csv.writer(f)

    a=[]

    def email_format():
            if 'E-Mail' in details.text:
                mail=details.img['src']
                email=mail.replace('typo3temp/GB/','').replace('%40','@').split('_')[0]
                return email
    for i in z:
        comp=requests.get('https://www.uae-business-directory.com/'+i['href']).text
        soup_comp=BeautifulSoup(comp,'lxml')
        details=soup_comp.find('div',class_='details')
        for i in details:
            print(i.text)
            music.writerow([i.get_text(),email_format()]) #Writing to CSV
            
        

z=comp_links()
comp_details(z)
```

And the Output is like this :

> ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING ESTBuilding ContractorsP.O. Box: 200Location: Umm Al QuwainPhone: 06-7655445

How can I get it like this:

- ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING EST
- Building Contractors
- P.O. Box: 200
- Location: Umm Al Quwain
- Phone: 06-7655445

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.uae-business-directory.com/directory/umm-al-quwain/umm-al-quwain/building-contractors/abdulla-salem-contracting-est.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.h1.parent.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
```

Prints:

```
ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING EST
Building Contractors
P.O. Box: 200
Location: Umm Al Quwain
Phone: 06-7655445
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the tag has `scrapy`, you could try this:

```
details = response.css(".details ::text").getall()
```

This will fetch the entire `div` in `details`.
Upon inspection, `details` has a structure like:

```
['\n',
 '\n',
 '<!--\ngoogle_ad_client = "ca-pub-7955553446826172";\ngoogle_ad_slot = "2007388357";\ngoogle_ad_width = 300;\ngoogle_ad_height = 600;\n//-->\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING EST',
 'Building Contractors',
 'P.O. Box: 200',
 'Location: Umm Al Quwain',
 'Phone: 06-7655445']
```

You can get the subarray by using `details[-5:]`. It returns

```
['ABDULLA SALEM CONTRACTING EST',
 'Building Contractors',
 'P.O. Box: 200',
 'Location: Umm Al Quwain',
 'Phone: 06-7655445']
```